# How to see Name, Database_ id, created date of all the databases present in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to see the name, database_id, created date of all the databases which are present in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough privileges then you can use:

```
 select name
 ,      database_id
 ,      create_date 
 from   [sys].[Databases]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Select name, database_id, create_date, * 
From [sys].[databases]
```

Comment: Wouldn't the star at the end additionally select also all other colmuns instead of only name, database_id, create_date?

Comment: You are right. I thought it could be usefull to see it since he does not know the sys.databases view. If he later need more info, he can look at it.